# scala test : how to mix parallel and sequential execution of FeatureSpec test suites

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scalatest

I have multiple suites written using FeatureSpec, I run then via command promt using >scala tests command or I run them via IDE, I am looking for a way where I can configure Test Suite sequence and which ones to run in sequence and which to run in parallel.

my suites look like :

**Suite1.scala ==>**

```
class Suite1 extends BaseFeatureSpec {

  feature("Feature1") {

    scenario("Scenario1") {//test code}
    scenario("Scenario2") {//test code}
}
```

}

**Suite2.scala ==>**

```
    class Suite2 extends BaseFeatureSpec {

      feature("Feature2") {

        scenario("Scenario3") {//test code}
        scenario("Scenario4") {//test code}
    }

}
```

**Suite3.scala ==>**

```
    class Suite3 extends BaseFeatureSpec {

      feature("Feature3") {

        scenario("Scenario5") {//test code}
        scenario("Scenario6") {//test code}
    }

}
```

***Now I want something like I can run Suite1 in parallel with (Suite 2 and Suite 3 in sequence) and pass different config to each set in parallel.***

Answer (score 0):

I added annotations to all the test classes,

```
@DoNotDiscover
class TestClass1 extends FeatureSpec 
{
   //code
}
```

then add distributor like as follows, in a new class

```
class TestDistributor extends Stepwise(

  Sequential(new TestClass2, new TestClass4)

)

class TestDistributor2 extends Stepwise(

  Sequential(new TestClass1, new TestClass3)

)
```

with this Test suites (2 and 4 will run in sequence) and in parallel to (1 and 3 in sequence)